# node/npm saying "Missing script <scriptname>" even though it exists in current directory

Tags: node.js, npm

The *package.json* is:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "find ./js/tests -name '*.test.js' | xargs mocha -R spec",
    "start": "node ./scores.js",
    "run": "node ./scores.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.734.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    .. 
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "name": "scores",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "something"
  }
}
```

`npm install` has been done and the `package-lock.json` created. Why are either `npm run` or `npm run-script` working?

```
$npm run-script ./scores.js
npm ERR! missing script: ./scores.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/steve/.npm/_logs/2021-03-01T23_01_56_745Z-debug.log
15:01:56/scores $ls -l scores.js
-rw-r--r--  1 steve  staff  21417 Feb 25 06:24 scores.js
```

I have identically structured package.json and scripts in other sibling directories that *do* work e.g.  the following works via `cd ../keys_server; npm run keys_server`

```
$cat ../keys_server/package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "find ./js/tests -name '*.test.js' | xargs mocha -R spec",
    "keys_server": "node ./keys_server.js",
    "start": "node ./keys_server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.734.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
      ..
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "name": "keys_server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "keys_server.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "something"
  },
```

**Update** @pkumar noticed that the *main* entry was left empty.  I now updated it to :

```
  "main": "scores.js",
```

and then tried both

`npm run-script ./scores.js` and `npm run scores` and `npm run scores.js`.  However none of them work:

> $npm run scores
>
> npm ERR! missing script: scores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'main' field is empty in package.json. try adding scores.js there and see if it works

The 'main' field is supposed to be the entry point of the server: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json

EDIT: The actual reason it's not working is because "scores" had not been defined under the scripts section. After adding that definition it should work

```
"scripts": {
      ..
      "scores": "node ./scores.js"
    }
```

Comment: hmmm after fixing by `"main" : "scores.js"` and invoking either `npm run-script ./scores.js` or `npm run score` it is _still_ not working.  I'm looking more..

Comment: Maybe you can compare the keys_server.js and scores.is files and see where the files differ. If it works in keys_server there's no reason for it to not work in scores.js

Comment: Turns out the `main` was not the issue: it's under "scripts" section: this should be added `    "scores": "node ./scores.js"`  . Why don't you update your answer and then you can get your first "win"

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Please explicitly add to your answer  "Should be added under the `scripts` section :   `"scores": "node ./scores.js"` .  Nmd I added it already.